# consulta para actualizar datos ya ingresados

Tags: php, html, sql, base-de-datos

Hola necesito ayuda para saber por que no se me actualizan los datos, ya revise las comillas simples y las dobles, tambien las variables y nombres de columnas creo que estan bien o sera la query del UPDATE? Si me muestra todos los datos agregados anteriormente pero al momento de modificar algo y guardarlo no me marca error ni me los modifica

```html
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $razonSocial = $_POST["razonsocial"];
    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $cliente = $_POST["Cliente"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];
    $moneda = $_POST["moneda"];
    $mercancia = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $importe = $_POST["importe"];
    $tipoOperacion = $_POST["TipoOperacion"];
    $detalles = $_POST["detalles"];
    $tipoTransporte = $_POST["TipoTransporte"];
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["FechaSalida"];
    $fechaLlegada = $_POST["FechaLlegada"];
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $porigen = $_POST["porigen"];
    $eorigen = $_POST["eorigen"];
    $corigen = $_POST["corigen"];
    $pdestino = $_POST["pdestino"];
    $edestino = $_POST["edestino"];
    $cdestino = $_POST["cdestino"];
    $cuota = $_POST["cuota"];
    $prima = $_POST["prima"];
    $gastosexp = $_POST["gastosexp"];
    $iva = $_POST["iva"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];

    query("UPDATE merca SET Cliente='".$cliente."', rfc='".$rfc."', moneda='".$moneda."', mercancia='".$mercancia."', importe='".$importe."', TipoOperacion='".$tipoOperacion."', detalles='".$detalles."', TipoTransporte='".$tipoTransporte."', FechaSalida='".$fechaSalida."', FechaLlegada='".$fechaLlegada."', folio='".$folio."' porigen='".$porigen."', eorigen='".$eorigen."', corigen='".$corigen."', pdestino='".$pdestino."', edestino='".$edestino."', cdestino='".$cdestino."', cuota='".$cuota."', prima='".$prima."', gastosexp='".$gastosexp."', iva='".$iva."', total='".$total."' WHERE idViaje=".$_GET["id"]);
}

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $result=query("SELECT  clientes.RazonSocial, clientes.RFC, clientes.Calle, clientes.Colonia, 
        clientes.Municipio, clientes.Estado, clientes.CP,
        merca.idViaje, merca.idCliente, merca.Cliente, merca.rfc, merca.moneda, 
        merca.mercancia, merca.importe, merca.TipoOperacion, 
        merca.detalles, merca.TipoTransporte, merca.FechaSalida, merca.FechaLlegada, 
        merca.folio, merca.porigen, merca.eorigen, merca.corigen, merca.pdestino, 
        merca.edestino, merca.cdestino, merca.poliza, merca.cuota, merca.prima, merca.gastosexp, 
        merca.iva, merca.total
FROM clientes join merca ON clientes.idCliente = merca.idCliente WHERE idViaje=".$_GET["id"]);
    $rowp = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form id="ncliente" name="ncliente" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Datos del Asegurado</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon Social</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input name="razonsocial" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowp["RazonSocial"]; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead_2 form-control" />
                                        <input id="idCliente" name="idCliente" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["idCliente"]; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Alta</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="datetime-local" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Beneficiario Preferente</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cliente</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="Cliente" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["Cliente"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">RFC</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="rfc" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["rfc"]; ?>"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Detalles del Certificado</h3>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Moneda</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="moneda" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["moneda"]; ?>"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado de la Mercancia</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="mercancia" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["mercancia"]; ?>"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="importe" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["importe"]; ?>"></div>

                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bienes Asegurados</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="TipoOperacion" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["TipoOperacion"]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripcion del Embarque</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="detalles" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["detalles"]; ?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Transito | Medio de Transporte</h3>
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class="col-sm-12"><input type="text" name="TipoTransporte" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["TipoTransporte"]; ?>"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Fecha de Salida</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="FechaSalida" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["FechaSalida"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Fecha de Llegada</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="FechaLlegada" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["FechaLlegada"]; ?>"></div>

                                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Folio Factura</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="folio" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["folio"]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Origen y Destino</h3>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="porigen" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["porigen"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="eorigen" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["eorigen"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Origen</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="corigen" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["corigen"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="pdestino" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["pdestino"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="edestino" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["edestino"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Destino</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="cdestino" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["cdestino"]; ?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Informacion de emision</h3>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Poliza</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="poliza" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["poliza"]; ?>" disabled></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="cuota" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["cuota"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="prima" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["prima"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gastos de Expedicion</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="gastosexp" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["gastosexp"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["iva"]; ?>"></div>
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control m-b" value="<?php echo $rowp["total"]; ?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: utilizas mysqli, en tu aplicación?

Comment: Si uso mysqli por? y en base de datos phpmyadmin

Comment: intenta ingresar los valores directamente en el script sql. hardcodea. para ver si funciona realmente la query

Comment: ??? ingreso los valores manualmente en el query UPDATE o a que te refieres o.O

Comment: query("Update merca Cliente= 'cliente' where id = " . $_GET["id"] . " ");   por cierto, no te indica algun error?

Comment: Pero esto: `query("UPDATE merca SET Cliente ...` ¿no lo asignas a nada? Asígnalo a una variable y comprueba su estado: `if ( $update=query("UPDATE merca SET Cliente...") ) {echo "Se actualizaron los datos" } else {echo "Hubo un error: ".mysqli_error();}`

Comment: Si lo estoy asignado query("UPDATE merca SET Cliente='".$cliente."') esa es la variable o a que te refieres

Comment: JuanL ya intente con tu query y siguie sin aplicar el UPDATE y no me marca ningun error

Comment: Estás seguro que ` WHERE idViaje=".$_GET["id"]` tiene el valor de la fila que quieres actualizar?

Comment: Si, lo hago mediante el id que se actualice (subí foto de la tabla)

Comment: [Revisa esto:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250203/problemas-con-la-obtencion-de-un-valor-en-php/250206#250206)

Comment: INSERT si puedo sin problemas, lo que no es el UPDATE