# Problemas con la obtencion de un valor en PHP

Tags: php

En mi codigo PHP obtengo el valor de un input pero lo que quiero hacer es darle un valor en el caso de que no exista dicho valor, por defecto los input no tienen ningun valor y me recoge correctamente los datos en las variables cuando coloco algo pero no se como comprobar cuando no hay nada para darle otro valor, yo lo hice de esta manera pero al parecer no es de esta forma asi que quisiera saber que tengo que hacer.

```
if(is_null($nombre)) {
   $nombre = $lista['nombre'];
}
```

Comment: Debes utilizar [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) en vez de un `is_null`

Comment: Cuando son muchos datos, yo expreso las relaciones en un array, así evitas el uso constante de `if` o de bloques `switch .. case`. Y si hay que agregar nuevas opciones, solamente se agregan en el array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con PHP 7, puedes usar el **`NULL COALESCENCE OPERATOR`**

```
$nombre = $lista['username'] ?? 'Sin valor asignado';
```

Donde:

- La variable `$nombre` es igual a '$lista['username']'
- En caso de no recibir el valor anterior, con el doble signo de `??` asignamos un valor por defecto que es: `Sin valor asignado`
- Este operador es similar en funcionamiento y longitud al operador ternario
- En este caso podrás evitar el uso de la función `isset()`

**EJEMPLO 1**

```
<?php

$lista['username'];

$nombre = $lista['username'] ?? 'Sin valor asignado';

echo $nombre;
```

Me va a devolver

> Sin valor asignado

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
<?php

$lista['username'] = "Pedro";

$nombre = $lista['username'] ?? 'Sin valor asignado';

echo $nombre;
```

Me da a devolver

> Pedro

Referencia al [operador](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: muchas gracias, me a sido de mucha ayuda, no conocia esa funcion de php

Comment: Buen dato @anonimo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como agregar un simple nombre a la base de datos:

Lo primero que uso es `isset` que determina si una variable está definida, mas en [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) y despues utilizo `empty` que determina si una variable está vacía, mas info en [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php).

No podras ingresar nada a la base de datos hasta no completar el campo nombre y para mas seguridad uso PDO - [Sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])){
        $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre) VALUES (:usuario)");
        $add->bindValue(':usuario', $_POST['nombre']);
        $add->execute();

        echo 'Usuario agregado con exito'; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'No se pudo agregar el usuario - campos vacios';
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
<button name="agregar">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = (isset($_GET['parametro']) ? $_GET['parametro'] : "algo por defecto" ;
```